# Unexpected increase of FS size used in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

We have the storage full on our AWS ubuntu instance just around a week back so we increased the storage from 8 GB to 15 GB

After somedays, MongoDB horribly takes 3 GB of FS size in just around 1 week.

```
{
"db" : "",
"collections" : 9,
"views" : 0,
"objects" : 2726,
"avgObjSize" : 4282.38554658841,
"dataSize" : 11673783.0,
"storageSize" : 7643136.0,
"numExtents" : 0,
"indexes" : 19,
"indexSize" : 835584.0,
"fsUsedSize" : 11096285184.0,
"fsTotalSize" : 15545323520.0,
"ok" : 1.0
```

}

So, according to db stats commands we have only 4 GB storage left now in just a week ? Isn't it suspicious ? Or Everything is fine ?

df -h says the same thing though:

[image]

My MongoDB version is: 4.0.3

My OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: did you perform heavy insert or index related operations?

Comment: No nothing like that we are using mid scale nodejs/express app with MongoDB thats it. @SaikatChakrabortty

Comment: Please let me know if you want more details to figure out the issue.

Comment: can you check the size of the data directory of the mongo? you can find the dire path in mongo conf. as dbpath i guess.

Comment: okay sure will let you know shortly

Comment: shockingly with du -h cmd the /data/db dir is only 512M @SaikatChakrabortty

Comment: so, i guess its not mongo who is consuming the memory, it might be something else, 
you can try to find big files in your system to know more about who is consuming, you can also find some commands to find, you can choose from here https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-largest-file-in-directory-recursively-using-find-du/

Comment: if its not mongo then why db stats is showing fsUsedSize to 11 GB. is it related to DB storage only or overall system ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200012/discussion-between-saikat-chakrabortty-and-a-khan).